# Updating a Classic ASP website without interrupting service

Tags: asp-classic

A couple of questions:

1) How can I update a Classic ASP website/page without interrupting service (users getting an error or service unavailable message) or shutting the website down temporarily?

2) When updating/restoring a MSSQL DB via SQL Server Management Studio, will the website users get an error message?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A smart practice is to use at least one separate development environment with the same setup as your production environment and debug all changes there to ensure that they work. Once your entire site is running and tested on the other, identical environment to your production environment, you should be able to simply move the files and they should work in production. This model being effective is dependent on actually being able to maintain environments as close to identical to each other as possible.

> When updating/restoring a MSSQL DB

Be careful with your terminology; UPDATE and RESTORE are two *very* different commands.

If the database is locked by the changes being made, then it will be inaccessible to users and may cause error messages depending on your IIS and code setup. Scheduling a maintenance period and blocking user access to any pages that access the database is will help avoid messy errors and revealing any information about your infrastructure while the changes are being made.

It seems like you might want to do some basic research on development and databases both in order to make sure you understand what you're doing and can cover all of your bases. Looking up commands like RESTORE and UPDATE and using them correctly is crucial.

> For example, when you rewrite one or more of your website files 
>      via FTP, in that very moment when rewriting is taking place, 
>      users will get a 500 Service Unavailable error. How can I avoid this?

This really shouldn't happen, although you could upload the files to a different folder, avoiding any delay there, and sync the files with a diff tool such as Winmerge (also helping you keep track of changes and revert quickly) when done uploading.

Comment: Thanks, your answer covered exactly what I needed to know.